# How is the Kanji of 口実 related to the meaning?

Tags: words

口実
noun:
excuse;  pretext

Literally translated it seems to mean mouth-truth.
Most excuses seem to avoid the truth, so what is the logic here?

Comment: Perhaps the kanji stands as opposed to 事実 (with the kanji pointing to a meaning of something like = truth of the matter). Compared with 口実 (with the kanji pointing to something like = stated/spoken truth).
Also the kanji 口 often pops up in words suggesting negative/deceptive speak even when the negative aspect is not obvious. E.g. 口先 lip service、口出し butting in、口答え back talk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kanji 実 means other things besides just "truth".  Take a look at the old form 實, or the older forms on [chineseetymology.org](http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?characterInput=%E5%AF%A6).  You can see three distinct components:

- A *roof* 宀, symbolizing a *building*
- A *crop field* 田 (sometimes written with extra dots to show that it is *full of crops*)
- A *shell* 貝 symbolizing *money, value* (of the crops)

Here's how Henshall explains these elements in *A Guide to Remembering Japanese Characters*:

> [This character] originally referred to a house made prosperous through bumper crops. The idea of house has now disappeared, leaving such meanings as **crop**, **fullness**, **substance**, **ripen**, and by extension **bear fruit** and **reality**.  Unusually, the semi-abstract idea of bumper crop was also extended to the physical crop, giving **fruit**, **nut**, etc.

So as you can see, you can't simply assume 実 means "truth".  In this case, the relevant meaning is "fullness", and the literal meaning of 口実 is "full mouth".  As explained by [gogen-online](http://gogen-allguide.com/ko/koujitsu.html), there are two things a mouth could be full of--either food or drink, or words--and 口実 came to refer to words directly, and specifically to excuses.

Answer (score 5):

Nice question!  From [the entry](http://gogen-allguide.com/ko/koujitsu.html) in the 語源由来辞典{ごげんゆらいじてん} for 口実{こうじつ}, it appears that 口実{こうじつ} used to mean something like "to have one's mouth full of food or words" *(but since Heian times, this word is typically referring more to "words" rather than food.*)

And ever since the Heian period, 口実{こうじつ} has come to mean something more like: "to unreasonably try to put truth into empty words".

It would then make sense how an excuse could be nothing but many empty words in one's mouth.